# Haskell type error matching Num a with Int

Tags: haskell

Why can't I do this?

```
genList :: Num a => Int -> [a]
genList m_size = [1..m_size]
```

It says:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `Int'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for genList :: Num a => Int -> [a]
          at uloha1.hs:105:12
    Relevant bindings include
      genList :: Int -> [a] (bound at uloha1.hs:106:1)
    In the expression: m_size
    In the expression: [1 .. m_size]
```

How come it cannot retype Int to Num implicitly? Int is instance of Num isn't it?
I can't find anything on this.
I am using latest Haskell platform Ghci
I am also completely new to haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell should never "retype" anything. You are probably confusing this with polymorphic number literals. However, `m_size` is not a literal and it is explicitly `Int`. You can write

```
[1 .. fromIntegral m_size]
```

but then you have still the problem that this construct needs also an `Enum` constraint.

An alternative would be

```
genList :: Enum a => Int -> [a]
genList m_size = [toEnum 1 .. toEnum m_size]
```

Since this works for any enum type, it works also for all numeric enum types.

Comment: Thank you! So basicly I cant use yhis construction, and have to think of something else, right? :)

Comment: You can simply add the Enum constraint, @Mylan719.

Comment: That is the problem, that I can't. I have obligatory type definition given like this: 
identity :: Num a => Int -> [[a]]
I simplyfied the problem to 1D array to be morev clear. I cant change the type definitin one bit. :) I though this notation would be handy, but it seems to do something else that I don't understand.

Comment: @Mylan719 What does this mean "I have obligatory type definitions"? You can tell the nice person that demands this, that it is impossible. You cannot, for **all numeric types**, go from 1 to some number, without at least comparing. And since `Ord` is not a superclass of `Num` in Haskell, your type is simply not constrained enough. It is as if someone asks you to make alcohol from just oxygen and carbon. It's not possible, you need also hydrogen.

Answer (score 2):

if you need exactly this signature you can still get it working - you just cannot use the `[x..y]` enumeration - a simple implementation would be this:

```
genList :: Num a => Int -> [a]
genList = reverse . genList'

genList' :: Num a => Int -> [a]
genList' 0 = []
genList' n = fromIntegral n : genList' (n-1)
```

and it should work as expected:

```
λ> genList 5 :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4,5]
λ> genList 5 :: [Double]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked around about this. I realized, that what I didn't understand, was haskell cannot "cast" anything. It can only make type more specific if it was too general before.

Therefore `1` is of type `Num` but by doing `1 + 1::Int` the result type becomes  `Int`. But it cannot go back from `Int` to `Num`.
So `[1..m_size]` is of type `[Int]` which is more concrete than `[Num]` and haskell cannot cast it, as I presumed it would because I am used to working with OO languages.

So a way around this would be similar to what  @Carsten said. I will generate list with elements of type `Int` first and than 'retype' it later. So somewhat more condensed solution would look like this:

```
genList :: Num a => Int -> [a]
genList n = map fromIntegral [1..n]
```

I was told that thanks to haskell lazy implementation, list elements will be iterated only once when being proccessed by `map`.

Thanks also to @Ingo @Kiraa @chepner for contributions, I basicaly tried to sum it up here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in retyping the Int to Num, it's in using the [1..m_size] notation without reassuring the compiler the `a` is implementing `Enum`. The type of the function should be

```
genList :: (Num t, Enum t) => t -> [t]
```

Comment: That does not solve my problem, unfortunately, I can't chenge type of the function. All I want to do is to generate List from 1 to m_size containing Nums, I don't see why elements of the list need to be enumerable.

Comment: `Enum` class says to compiler that he will be able to assume predecessor and successor of a value. To generate a List of something given the smallest and the biggest element, you need to know the successor of the first, then the successor of the second, etc.

Comment: No I don't I ask it to generate me list of numbers [1,2,3,4,...,m_size], It has nothing to do with what a is. 1 is Int and is Enum type and m_size is also Int and enum type.

Comment: this is not the problem here as `[1..m_size]` is perfectly fine as `m_size :: Int` is an instance of `Enum` (and `Ord` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just because an `Int` is an instance of `Num` doesn't mean it is equivalent to *any* type that could be declared an instance of `Num`. Consider

```
genList 1000 :: [Int8]
```

`Int8` is an instance of `Num`, but in general an `Int` (and specifically in this case, 1000) is not a value of type `Int8`.

Assuming we aren't going to change the definition of your function (see the other answers for how to do that), we can do one of two things:

1. Leave the argument type set to `Int`, and realize that we *must* return a list of `Int`s as well, since we haven't specified a way to create a list of another type.

   ```
   genList :: Int -> [Int]
   ```
2. Allow a less general output type, which dictates what input types are allowed. Similar to the other answer, `ghci` can infer a valid function type from your definition: `genList :: (Enum t, Num t) => t -> [t]`. That is, you can return a `[t]` for any type `t`, as long as the input type is also `t` and that type is an instance of both `Enum` and `Num`.